# @XmlTransient marked value returns null when unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am using `@XmlTransient` for hiding some Strings in output XML file. It works fine while marshalling and the XML is fine.
 However when I unmarshall the XML, the `@XmlTransient` marked values appear as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What `@XmlTransient` Does**

`@XmlTransient` marks the property as unmapped so it is excluded from both marshalling and unmarshalling.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

---

**What You Could Do**

If you just want to exclude the value from marshalling you may consider using an `XmlAdapter`

***XmlAdapter (StringAdapter)***

The `XmlAdapter` will always return `""` for the marshal operation and the JAXB implementation will return an empty element.  If you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB implementation you could return null to eliminate the node completely (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html).

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return string;
    }

}
```

***Person***

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    String name;

    String address;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringAdapter.class)
    String password;

}
```

***input.xml***

```xml
<Person>
    <name> some name </name>
    <password> some password </password>
    <address> some address </address>
</Person>
```

***Demo***

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14231799/input.xml");
        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(person.password);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

```xml
 some password 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person>
    <name> some name </name>
    <address> some address </address>
    <password></password>
</Person>
```

Comment: During marshalling the marshall method in StringAdapter is called. However while unmarshalling unmarshal method is not called. What could be the issue.

Comment: @AnandB - It will only be called if there is content in the XML corresponding to that property.  The easiest way to see what content it is expecting is to unblock the property for the marshal operation and produce a sample doc.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should return String instead of null in marshal method in StringAdapter and verify content in output xml

Comment: I tried it. The element now appears in the xml file. It has a valid value. Now when I try to unmarshall, the unmarshall method in StringAdapter is called

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the element from appearing in the xml in the above case

Comment: @AnandB - I don't understand your use case, can you provide more details?

Comment: I have a class Person with String values name,Address,password.

The XML should display only the name and Address element.The password element should be hidden to user. When I unmarshall the XML file, I need to retrive the password value. Is this possible
`code`
public class Person{

    @XmlElement

    private String name;

   @XmlElement
    private String Address;
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringAdapter.class)
    private String password;

}
The output xml should be like
<Person>
 <name> some name </name>
 <address> some address </address>
</Person>
`code`

Comment: @AnandB - I have added a complete example to my answer which should help.